# Should we award a badge to someone sharing a link to a question leading to a nice answer from a new user?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Let's say that I've come across an unanswered question that could be answered by someone that I know but who is not a registered member of Stack Overflow.

[image]

That person goes through the sign up process first, then provides an answer which later turns out to be a nice answer (i.e. score of 10 or more).

The idea is to reward those who attract "new talents" to the community.

*Please note that I deliberately used the term "nice answer" here in order to prevent an obvious abuse of the system.*

Is this something that has been considered before?

Comment: +1 I like the idea. Getting helpful people into the community is important. However, it seems a bit hard, especially if you only have one chance. I suggest +5, and maybe (?) that the user just has to be a new contributor, not just the first post. Feel free to object.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My main question is whether it would be worth rewarding those contributing to the community by attracting new helpful contributors. How this should be appropriately measured is up for debate obviously. Perhaps my own suggestion on that is too difficult indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the freehand, by the way :)

Comment: You are probably talking about the existing "Announcer" badge.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78160/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work

Comment: Not quite. My suggestion is more about rewarding those who share a link that result into an accepted answer to the question. I don't think that is covered in that post. (Unless I'm misunderstanding something.)

Comment: Isn't this what the [announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) already does?

Comment: @Liam It's a bit different I think. The announcer badge rewards those who drive traffic by sharing links, whereas my proposal is to reward those who contributed to get an accepted answer to a question by sharing a link to it.

Comment: Let face it, SE inc. aren't going to invest time and money into this. There is a similar badge and they gain no revenue. You're probably about 5 years too late with this, they may of listened to you then. Add it to the list of things asked for on here and promptly ignored.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm not sure any of the existing badges were designed to gain revenue. They exist to reward those who made significant contributions to the community. I believe my suggestion is aimed towards the same goal. If the community as a whole think that this is a good thing, there is no reason to believe that SE inc won't even consider it. Whether that's feasible is a different matter of course.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an interesting idea.

However, I don't think it should be tied to score. Simply tie it to whether the answer was accepted or not.

I am also slightly skeptical ([knowing how complicated the account creation success method is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207388/178816)) that it is possible from a technical standpoint to actually track that the shared link resulted in not only an account creation but an answer placed to the linked question.

Assuming it was possible, perhaps something along the lines of:

> Bronze
>   "Share a link which results in a new user whose answer is then accepted."

> *Silver*
>   "Share 25 links which result in 25 users who then have their answers accepted."

> ***Gold***
>   "Share 100 links which result in 100 users who then have their answers accepted."

It would certainly be nice from an onboarding point of view. From a technical standpoint it could be rather difficult to implement.

Comment: I like this idea, but it can be cheated. What about adding a bit on to the end: "...their answers accepted **with a positive score**", so that A: the post helped the community and B: It wasn't a rigged accept. Possibly replace "positive score" with "score +3" to make cheating it even harder.

Comment: @EthanK888 - Cheated? There are safeguards against users accepting sock account answers, as that would be reputation manipulation. I highly doubt anyone would create a large number of throw away accounts just to get this one badge, and if they did it would be very obvious. I don't think there is any need to put any more excessive technical requirements on this already rather involved feature.

Comment: I was meaning that **and** that a good score (say just positive) could make sure that the question is good.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of a badge linked to sharing a post. It might make more people share, which is good. However, I think that while a badge for sharing to a non-user is a good idea, it might make a bit more sense just to get the badge for sharing a link to anyone and it gets a good score by another person (+5 or +10 or something). It doesn't matter if it is a to-be user or an old one (although the first one is better), as you helped that great answer be created.

#### Yes, let's do this!

So my opinion is that this should **definitely** be a thing. You helped make that great post happen, and so you should be rewarded. That just makes sense.

Here is my view on the badge(s) that I think should be added. Feel free to share your personal thoughts on what you think (Is the score needed for all of them right? Should *all* of these be added?).

> #### [Sharer] <sup><sub>(Bronze)</sub></sup>
>
> Share a post with another user, gets 8+ score and question score ≥ 0.

---

> #### [Proclaimer] <sup><sub>(Silver)</sub></sup>
>
> Share a post with another user, gets 20+ score and question score ≥ 0.

---

Possibly a gold variant of the first two, but I don't really know. Should there be a gold one, or is gold too much?

---

> #### [Starter] <sup><sub>(Silver)</sub></sup>
>
> Share a post with a user with no answers beforehand, gets 5+ score and question score ≥ 0.

How do you feel about these?

Comment: You may be right that it doesn't matter whether a user was already registered or no when they gave their answer. However I'm not sure linking the question score is relevant; you can still provide a good answer to a question you don't think is a good one. Or were you more thinking of wether the question was a good one at the time a user gave an answer?

Comment: @customcommander I was thinking of using it as a way to make sure the question that you share is "okay". It may have been better to say "score ≥ 0", I will edit.

Comment: @customcommander I also just noticed I had typed "answer" instead of "question". Opps! I meant "\[answer\] get 5+ score and ***question*** gets +3", not "*answer* +3" Sorry! I totally messed up my wording, no wonder the downvote. It is fixed.